# What is the name of this plant, from Bangladesh?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is a small plant from my backyard. I have found the flower closes in the evening.

Comment: You would like to compare it with a related species which is also common in the same locality. http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50513/want-to-identify-plant-and-flower

Comment: what could be the butterfly on the first image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plant belong to Malvaceae, and the yellow flowers open towards morning to mid-day.

This plant is most-likely *Sida rhombifolia* or may be *Malvastrum tricuspidatum* .

From broad leaves it seems not *Sida acuta*

Check epicalyx ( made up of bracteoles)... is there is no epicalyx then *Sida rhombifolia*.
If epicalyx is 3, it is *Malvastrum tricuspidatum*

look also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sida_rhombifolia,

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Roi0lwSXFnUC&lpg=PA258&ots=N7DNvrN4UL&dq=malvastrum%20tricuspidatum%203%20epicalyx&pg=PA258#v=onepage&q=malvastrum%20tricuspidatum%203%20epicalyx&f=false

Epicalyx of *Malvastrum tricuspidatum* :

[image: Malvastrum tricuspidatum corolla calyx epicalyx]

C= Corolla (all petals), K= Calyx (all sepals), E= Epicalyx the bracteole

[image: 3 bracteoles]

3 bracteoles

Comment: I'd recommend adding an explanation of how to check the epicalyx and elaborating on 'if epicalyx is 3' (I know it's in the link but it's good practice to put this in the answer).