# Want to identify plant and flower

Tags: species-identification

[image]

This plant is hardly 40/50 days old and given to me in seed form claiming to be hibiscus plant seed.I m not sure that it s hibiscus plant.. Please identify.

Comment: Definitely not hibiscus.

Comment: Please state where in the world this plant is located, or native to. There are lots of yellow flowers in the world.

Comment: I agree with @WYSIWYG. No way this is [hibiscus](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Hibiscus_pink.jpg). Can you provide more details? e.g. undershot of leaves, texture of plant/leaves (are they fuzzy? prickly? ), size.

Comment: Good resource: http://midatlantichikes.com/floraandfauna/yellowflowers.htm

Comment: You would like to compare with a related species: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39532/what-is-the-name-of-this-plant-from-bangladesh/50561#50561 . I assume This photo is taken from India or Bangladesh. I'm from India, and its very common plant in our locality.

Comment: Malvaceae. *Sida* sp. Most-likely *Sida cordifolia* , or maybe *Sida humilis*

Comment: let the plant grow-up and watch the fruit

Comment: The fruit of *Sida* and *Abutilon* are  very-much distinctive

Comment: The flower looks much like *Abutilon* , since it is much widely open